# Resizing Extended Partition w/ gparted on livecd

Tags: 16.10, gparted

As you can see, I have swapoff and don't have any of the partitions mounted.

[image]

I want to increase the size of /dev/sda1, and in order to do that I have to shrink /dev/sda2.  I have unallocated space in /dev/sda2 but this is what I see when I try to shrink it.

[image]

I've read other answers to similar questions but in those cases the OP seems to not be using a live cd or has swap on.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I'm currently attempting a solution 
[image]

EDIT 2: While running gparted, my computer froze when it tried to go to sleep, so I ended up having to reinstalling from scratch. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't resize sda2 because the unallocated space is between sda6 and sda5. To expand sda1 using the unallocated space inside sda2, you need to do the following:

1. move sda6 below (to the right) the unallocated space, such that there is no more space between sda6 and sda5.
2. resize sda2 such that its size = sda6 + sda5. This will move the unallocated space ahead (to the left) of sda2, and just after sda1.
3. expand sda1 to make use of the unallocated space.

You need to understand that sda2 is an extended partition, consisting of sda6, the unallocated space, and sda5. Shrinking sda2 will only be possible if there are unallocated space to the extreme left or extreme right of the extended partition.

Comment: Be sure to have good backups. A partition move with lots of data can take a very long time. Any interruption will totally corrupt it and all data is then lost.